# What is the correct way of integrating in astronomy simulations?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, astronomy, newtonian-gravity, simulations, integration

I'm creating a simple astronomy simulator that should use Newtonian physics to simulate movement of plants in a system (or any objects, for that matter). All the bodies are circles in an Euclidean plane, that have properties such as position, velocity, mass, radius and the resultant force.

I want to update the universe in small time steps, usually a few milliseconds, but I'm not sure how to correctly calculate the changes in position.

The force is simple: `fr = sum(G * body.m * bodyi.m / dist(body, bodyi)^2)`.

But how do I go on from there?

I could do this:

```
a = Fr/body.m
v += a*dt
position += v*dt
```

But that would, of course, be false. Maybe if I added `0.5` as a factor in position calculation?

Comment: The FAQ says *'Some kinds of questions should not be asked here: [...] Computational questions'*. See [the scientific computation beta site](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/). But search first as I think this has already been addressed. There are also several such questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: And don't fret the silly automatic down vote: it will time out in a few days.

Comment: I reposted it on the computation site. Also, if you see  those similar questions on SO, please throw me a link.

Comment: I don't have any particular questions in mind, but [searches like "planet gravity"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=planet+gravity&submit=search) turn up some possibilities that look promising.

Comment: @dmckee automatic downvote, WTF ...?! Who has implemented such a needless and mean thing into SE? I quite often disagree about how things work or are implemented by the "overlords" into the SE sites against the will or needs of the respective communities, but such a thing is really over the top now ...! So I +1 the question to revert it

Comment: Well, I remember there being a competition on SO which centered around creating automatic moderators or something. You got a dataset, and had to use some statistical and AI methods of finding bad posts. Maybe it has to do with that...

Comment: No, that was not about creating automatic moderators. It was about creating the best possible algorithm to identify likely low-quality posts for moderators to review. The automatic downvote when a question is closed as off topic or NaRQ has been around for much longer, at least a couple years I think.

Comment: @Dilaton IIRC  the automatic downvote is for off-topic and not a real question only, and it is because only questions with a score lower than 0 are subject to automatic deletion. So it last just long enough for the auto-deleter to have a chance to look at it. It's not really important for us, but on Stack Overflow they gets *hundreds* or seriously deficient questions per day and the system is optimized so that they can be rapidly deleted. You can poke around on the mother meta if you want an official explanation.

Comment: @Dmckee ok I see that they probably have such an issue on SO and therefor need that feature over there. But that should not give them an excuse for playing such mean tricks all over the SE network, including science and beta sites or smaller communities too!

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky, that's exactly what I meant by "automatic moderators".